# Finding the median and modes of a discrete uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**Question** Let $X$ be Discrete Uniform on $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}.$ Find all medians and modes of $X$.

So far, I know that $P(x)=\frac{1}{n}$. By intuition, the median is $\frac{n+1}{2}$ for odd numbers. I have no idea how to put this in a story proof sort of way, and how to calculate the median and means for both odd and even cases. This is a problem given in the textbook that I came across during practice.

Comment: I believe the question is asking about the median and modes of a _distribution,_ not a sample. For $n = 6,$ it would be the 'fair die' distribution that puts probability $1/6$ at each of the values $1,2,3,4,5,6.$ So the median of this distribution is $\eta = 3.5$ and (depending on definition) there is no mode or there multiple modes at each of the six equally likely values.

Comment: @BruceET If you accept multiple modes, then you should be able to accept multiple medians, so for even $n$ either $\left[ \frac n2, \frac n 2 +1 \right]$ or  $\left\{ \frac n2, \frac n 2 +1 \right\}$ depending on whether the median should be part of the support

Comment: I view the issues with medians and modes to be quite different, but I don't disagree with your suggestion for medians. [In general, are there multiple modes only if all have the same max density/rel.freq., or does any local maximum qualify as a (perhaps) 'minor' mode?]

Answer (score 1):

If the cumulative distribution function is strictly increasing, you can define the median $M$ unambiguously as

$$M=F_X^{-1}(0.5)$$

in which $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of your variable $X$. But this definition does not make sense for a discrete distribution, since the cumulative distribution is not injective, and hence non-invertible.

A possible solution is to define a pseudo-inverse $F_X^{-}$ as follows

$$F_X^{-}(y)=\inf\{x \in \mathbb{R}|F_X(x)\geq y\}$$

You can now define the median as being $F_X^-(0.5)$. If you apply this definition on a uniform discrete distribution on the numbers $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, you get $3$ as a result. While applying it on the dice ($n=6$) will get you $3$. Maybe you're not very satisfied with that last result. So let's try another definition.

We now define $F_X^{+}$ as

$$F_X^{+}(y)=\sup\{x \in \mathbb{R}|F_X(x)\leq y\}$$

The median now becomes $F_X^{+}(0.5)$. Let's see what that gives us for our previous distributions. For the case of the uniform discrete distribution on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, we still get $3$, but for the dice we now get $4$. Still not happy I suppose?

But wait, can't we just take the mean of those two? In fact, you can do even more you can define

$$F_X^{\alpha}(y)=\alpha F_X^{-}(y)+(1-\alpha)F_X^{+}(y)$$

for any $\alpha \in [0,1]$. It is now clear that if we pick $\alpha=0.5$, we will get exactly what we wanted! In the even case, the median will be $\frac{n+1}{2}$.

Comment: For continuous distributions as well, there can be several medians.

Comment: True, I didn't think more deeply about it, but it is easy to construct continuous distributions which are non-injective and that therefore have the same ambiguity problem in defining the median as discrete distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Modes are local maximums of the PDF, therefore there are $n$ modes: 1, 2,...,$n$. In this case you can see that talking about a mode does not make much sense, or at least is not really enlightening (but then again, you already know that the random variable is uniform...)

The median depends on whether $n$ is even of odd.

- If $n$ is odd, then there is a single median, ${n+1}\over2$.
- If $n$ is even then any value in the (closed) interval [${n\over2},
     {n\over2}+1$] qualifies as a median.

This with the following definition of a median : any value $m$ such that 
$$
P(X<m)\leq .5 \quad \text{and } P(X>m)\leq .5.
$$
Of course the *default* median is ${n+1}\over2$ regardless of $n$.