# Mode Median for discrete uniform

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X$ is a discrete uniform distribution on $1, 2, \ldots,n$. I know that the median is $\frac{n+1}2$ for odd $n$. I need to find median when $n$ is even. Would it be $\frac{n}2$ or $\frac{n}2+1$, whichever is greater?

Also, is every point mode as PDF has highest values there? So there are $n$ modes - $1,2,\ldots,n$?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507016/finding-the-median-and-modes-of-a-discrete-uniform-distribution

Comment: And looking at some definitions is not an option because?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

To answer the first question, think of how to handle the case where $n=2$.

what is the median for uniform distribution on $1,2$?

For the second question, yes, there are $n$ modes.

Comment: 1 and 2 both will be the medians, right?

Comment: what is the definition of median to you?

Comment: For median m, P(X<=m) = P(X>=m) = 1/2

Comment: Here that point would be 0.5

Comment: But as this is discrete random variable, we can choose only 1 or 2

Comment: As X is a discrete uniform distribution on 1,2,…,n, as far as I know, X can take values out of these n values only. So for distribution on 1,2 , won't it have just these two values?

Comment: There is no such rule that they must take those values only unless you redefine the definition of medium. If you use your definition then medium does not exists as $P(X \geq 1) = 1$ and $P(X \leq 2) =1$. I am not aware of such practice as it would make the summary statistics very useless. Medium, and mean are summary statistics, it would be very restricted to limit their values to values that they can only take.

Comment: Oh ok! All the values in  [n/2,n/2+1] are medians then by definition for even n.

Comment: remember to exclude the boundary point.

Comment: Can I answer my question as (n/2, n/2+1) for closure?

Comment: I think that is alright, though if I were to pick a representative number, I would pick one right in the middle. I am uncertain whether a single answer is expected or every possible medium is wanted if this is a homework exercise.